# Passing variables into the ggplot aes

Tags: r, ggplot2

**This works:**

```
plot_interaction_term = function(df)
{
  print(ggplot(data=df, mapping=aes(y=new_confirmed, x=cumulative_vaccine_doses_administered_pfizer, color=cut(cumulative_vaccine_doses_administered_moderna, breaks=c(-Inf, Inf)))) 
        + geom_point()
        + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE))
}

plot_interaction_term(df)
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
plot_interaction_term = function(df, explanatory_variable1, explanatory_variable2)
{
  print(ggplot(data=df, mapping=aes(y=new_confirmed, x=explanatory_variable1, color=cut(explanatory_variable2, breaks=c(-Inf, Inf)))) 
        + geom_point()
        + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE))
}

plot_interaction_term(df, "cumulative_vaccine_doses_administered_pfizer", "cumulative_vaccine_doses_administered_moderna")
```

> ERROR:   Error in cut.default(explanatory_variable2, breaks = c(-Inf,
> Inf)) :    'x' must be numeric

2nd try:

```
plot_interaction_term(df, cumulative_vaccine_doses_administered_pfizer, cumulative_vaccine_doses_administered_moderna)
```

> ERROR:  Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :    object
> 'cumulative_vaccine_doses_administered_pfizer' not found

3rd try:

```
plot_interaction_term(df, df["cumulative_vaccine_doses_administered_pfizer"], df["cumulative_vaccine_doses_administered_moderna"])
```

> Error in cut.default(explanatory_variable2, breaks = c(-Inf, Inf)) :
> 'x' must be numeric

How do I get this to work?

```
print(df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `.data`

```
plot_interaction_term = function(df, explanatory_variable1, explanatory_variable2)
{
  print(ggplot(data=df, mapping=aes(y=new_confirmed, x=.data[[explanatory_variable1]], color=cut(.data[[explanatory_variable2]], breaks=c(-Inf, Inf)))) +
        geom_point() +
         geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE))
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is happening in the syntax `.data[[explanatory_variable1]]`? Intuitively, I would expect it to just be `data[explanatory_variable1]` where `data` is referring the to `df` object.

Comment: @NoName. the `[` is still a data.frame/tibble instead of a vector and `cut` requires a vector as input

Comment: @NoName It is not `data`, but `.data`, which is a data pronoun.  For more info, you can check `?".data"` or `?"tidyeval-data"`